# Windows 8 / XAML Double Tap event always preceded by Tap

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, touch, double-click

I've got a button in an app. I want it to do different things depending on whether I tap it (pause an animation) or double-tap (restart the animation)

however, when I double-tap, it seems to fire the tap event first and then the double-tap in quick succession. Is there a way around this? Is this a known issue or am I making a rookie mistake?

Edit: For those asking, I'm using the `Tapped` and `DoubleTapped` events.

Comment: some code would be good e.g. are you using DoubleTapped() or MouseDoubleClicked(); on second thoughts why don't you just have the single tap toggling the animation, seems much more noob user friendly / intuitive.

Comment: It's a timer, and single tap pauses the timer, while a double-tap resets it completely.

Comment: So why not have single tap pause the timer, and if the user single taps again and the timer is paused, allow the timer to continue? i.e. toggle the timer on off with a single click.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to consider letting it do both. Think about it like double clicking a folder in windows. Users will be used to something happening on the first click (highlighting the folder) and they will be expecting the double click to both highlight, then navigate.

All in all it seems like a design issue, not a technical one.

Comment: you could be right. I may be able to catch it with logic. I just wondered if I was using the wrong events

Answer (score 18):

Give the  some pause to single tab . If there is double tab occur then single tab event eliminated

```
  bool singleTap;
    private async void control_Tapped_1(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.singleTap = true;
        await Task.Delay(200);
        if (this.singleTap)
        {
              // Single tab Method .
        }
    }

    private void control_DoubleTapped_1(object sender, DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.singleTap = false;

        // Double tab Method  
  }
```

Comment: I personally feel this is the best way to it!!

Answer (score 0):

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern uint GetDoubleClickTime();
    bool _singleTapped = false;

        //Tapped event handler
        private async void control_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        _singleTapped = true;
            //var x = GetDoubleClickTime();
            //GetDoubleClickTime() gets the maximum number of milliseconds that can elapse between a first click and a second click
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(GetDoubleClickTime()));

            if (!_singleTapped)
            { return; }
           //SingleTapped code
        }

        //DoubleTapped event handler
        private async void control_DoubleTapped(object sender, DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _singleTapped = false;
            //DoubleTapped code
        }
```